# How do I create a directive with a controller in a way where the scope will work without having to use $parent in the view?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I need to include a controller as an attribute of my-modal. In my example, showModal is not in scope unless I use $parent.showModal = false. I can't use $parent in the view for the sake of other developers working on it. There are also many places in the app where other modals with different controllers are used in this same type of way.

#### Jade

```
div(ng-controller="itemsController", ng-init="showModal = false")
    a(href="", ng-click="showModal = true") Add an Item
    div(my-modal="showModal", ng-controller="newItemController")
        header
            h3 A Title
            a(href="", ng-click="showModal = false") X

   .body
        p Some text about this modal
        button(ng-click="showModal = false; create(foo);") DO IT
```

#### Directive

```
.directive 'myModal', ->
    restrict: 'A'
    scope: {
        myModal: '='
    }
    link: (scope, element, attrs) ->

        scope.$watch 'myModal', (current, previous) ->
            if scope.myModal is true
                element.css(display: 'block')
            else
                element.css(display: 'none')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a Singleton Factory service instead.

Something like:

$modal

- registerDialog(key);
- showModal(key);
- hideModal();

That way, the $modal service could be injected into any controller when and if you really need it.  In fact, the other controllers do not need to know anything about $modal service or even that it exists.

Next, I would recommend that you implement declarative directives for triggering and closing your modal dialog.

Any apps that need the modal dialog functionality, needs to add the ngModal as a module dependency and then add some directives to your page:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngModal']);
...
<body ng-app="myApp">
     <button ng-modal-show="OpenFileDialog">Click to Open Dialog 1</button>
     <div ng-modal="OpenFileDialog"> ... <button ng-modal-close>Close Dialog</button> </div>
```

Here is a really simple example:

[Modal Dialog for Angular JS](https://github.com/trees4/ng-modal)